# Magento 2 Error mini cart not show the products Error return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type))

Tags: magento-2.1.3, mini-cart

I have a custom template and i copied the all files

> module-checkout/view/frontend

and i paged to my custom template

> /Magento_Checkout

but i have an error in the console and the minicart in the front not list the products

[image]

[image]

Error `Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
Message: Cannot read property 'simple' of undefined`

My version magento is ver. 2.1.3

Thanks

Comment: Where is your template ?? 
How did you override ???